# Python Tkinter destroy window with a method

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm a new student to Python, I'm sorry if my code is horrible. I'm trying to run a GIF animation of "loading" while the web scrape takes place. The issue is I cant get the toplevel window to destroy after the scrape completes.

I have looked at many videos and other posts on here none have worked. toplevel.destroy() seems to be the common suggestion but its not working.

## my main window

```py
class App:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.geometry('1000x500+100+100')
        self.parent.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.parent.title('Class Project')

        self.canvas1 = tkinter.Canvas(parent, height=500, width=1000)
        filename = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "background.png")
        background_label = tkinter.Label(self.canvas1, image=filename)
        background_label.image = filename
```

## The new window

```py
        
    def new_window(self):
        self.newWindow = tkinter.Toplevel()
        self.app = LoadingScreen(self.newWindow) 
                 
class LoadingScreen:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title('Loading....')
        self.parent.geometry('350x270+100+100')
        self.parent.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(parent)
        self.canvas.pack()
```

## after the scrape I call the close

```py
 LoadingScreen.close_window()
```

```py
 def close_window():
        toplevel.destory()
```

toplevel.destory()

> NameError: name 'toplevel' is not defined

So far every thing works, just can not get the window to close.

Comment: The error message means exactly what it says--that the variable named `toplevel` is not a variable that you've set before. But it does look like you've set attributes of your objects to a `tkinter.Toplevel` object, so you might just need to use one of those attributes. If that error message isn't clear to you, you might want to read about variables and object attributes in a Python tutorial.

Comment: Your `toplevel` is held in `self.newWindow`, hence, if you want to destroy it, you call `self.newWindow.destroy()`

Comment: @ChuckG  That worked, Thank you. Through very poor class structure I wasn't pulling the self into the close_window method.

Comment: @DanGetz , Thank you, Yes i'm going to re-watch several tutorials. I thought I understood these concepts, but when you're knee deep in it you really see how much you truly know. I still have a lot to learn, Thanks for your time and patience.